# Use Jquery to show/not show text boxes depending on Dropdownlist selection

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have avoided using jquery as long as I can as every time I have tried I have had problems.  But today I am determined to get this working.  Using VS 2013, asp.net and VB.

I have a dropdownlist called AssetStatusChoice, and when the user selects a value from it I want certain text boxes to be visible or not.  The AssetStatuschoice DDL is populated from a database on SQL server 2012.

The text boxes are contained within a panel that pops up on the page when a row of a gridview is clicked.

The Jquery is as follows.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()  {
        $('#LowerText').hide();
        $('#UpperText').hide();
        $('#AssetStatusChoice').change(function () {
            if($('#AssetStatusChoice').val("Fully Available"))
            {
                $('#CommentsText').hide();
            }
            if ($('#AssetStatusChoice').val("Restricted"))
            {
                $('#UpperLimit').show();
                $('#LowerLimit').show();
            }
            if ($('#AssetStatusChoice').val("Unavailable"))
            {
                $('#Commentstext').show();
            }
        });
    });
```

The asp.net is as follows.

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="AssetPopUp" runat="server" PopupControlID="ChangeStatusPnl" TargetControlID="lnkFake"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
               <asp:Panel ID="ChangeStatusPnl" runat="server">
                <table id="PopUpTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" align="center">
                            <asp:Label ID="AssetName" runat="server" Text="Label" style="font-weight:bold;"></asp:Label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="DateText" runat="server" style="font-family:'Century Gothic'; font-size:18pt;"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="DateText"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
            <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="DateWaterMark" runat="server" TargetControlID="DateText" WatermarkText="Date"></ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>

                             </td>
                        <td> 
            <asp:TextBox ID="TimeTextHrs" runat="server" style="font-family:'Century Gothic'; font-size:18pt;"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TimeHrsWaterMark" runat="server" TargetControlID="TimeTextHrs" Watermarktext="Hrs"></ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TimeTextMins" runat="server" style="font-family:'Century Gothic'; font-size:18pt;"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TimeMinsWaterMark" runat="server" TargetControlID="TimeTextMins" Watermarktext="Mins"></ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>

                                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="AssetStatusChoice" runat="server" DataSourceID="AssetChoiceDDL" style="font-family:'Century Gothic'; font-size:18pt;" DataTextField="AssetStatus" DataValueField="AssetStatus" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Select a Value"></asp:ListItem>

                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="AssetChoiceDDL" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Optimiser_TestConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="getAssetAvailList" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="LowerText" runat="server" style="font-family:'Century Gothic'; font-size:18pt;"></asp:TextBox>
                            <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="LowerTextExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="LowerText" WatermarkText="Lower Limit"></ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="UpperText" runat="server" style="font-family:'Century Gothic'; font-size:18pt;"></asp:TextBox>
                            <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="UpperTextExtender" runat="server"  TargetControlID="UpperText" WatermarkText="Upper Limit"></ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Min:<asp:Label ID="MinValue" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td>Max:<asp:Label ID="MaxValue" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="CommentsText" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" style="height:100px; width:517px; font-family:'Century Gothic'; font-size:18pt;"></asp:TextBox>
                            <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="CommentsExtender" runat="server"  TargetControlID="CommentsText" WatermarkText="Comments"></ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" align="center">
                            <asp:Button ID="ClosePopUp" runat="server" Text="Close" style="font-family:'Century Gothic'; font-size:18pt;"/>
<asp:Button ID="CommitChanges" runat="server" Text="Commit" style="font-family:'Century Gothic'; font-size:18pt;"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>               
</asp:Panel>
```

Basically nothing happens, as you can see in the jquery I want to hide both Lowertext and Uppertext when the panel appears but this doesn't happen.  The panel loads all the text boxes, when I change the DDL nothing happens.

UPDATE

Thanks for the 2 suggestions but its still not working.  its as though it cant find the controls within the panel.  I added a textbox to the page (not in the panel) and added  `$('#textbox1').hide();` to the JQuery and this hid the text box.

UPDATE 2

I forgot to mention that the textboxes are also in an UpdatePanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it.

As there is an updatepanel I had to add the following to my code within the update panel.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                                 Sys.Application.add_load(jScript);
        </script>
```

I then updated my jquery to the following.

```
    <script>
    function jScript() {

            $('#LowerText').hide();
            $('#UpperText').hide();
            $('#min').hide();
            $('#max').hide();
            $('#AssetStatusChoice').change(function () {
            if ($('#AssetStatusChoice').val() == "Fully Available")
            {
                $('#CommentsText').hide();
            }
            if ($('#AssetStatusChoice').val() == "Restricted")
            {
                $('#LowerText').show();
                $('#UpperText').show();
            }
            if ($('#AssetStatusChoice').val() == "Unavailable")
            {
                $('#Commentstext').show();
            }
        });
        };

            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the value `val("value")`which returns a jQuery object.

Change your if conditions `like val()=="valueToTest"`.

```
 if($('#AssetStatusChoice').val("Fully Available"))
```

to

```
if($('#AssetStatusChoice').val()==="Fully Available")
```

**Also**

```
$('#AssetStatusChoice').val()==="Restricted"

$('#AssetStatusChoice').val()==="Unavailable"
```

Comment: that doesn't appear to change anything.  Also when the panel first opens the uppertext and lowertext textboxes are showing which they shouldn't be according to the jquery code.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to the answer that Murali posted:
See if this works

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()  {
        $('#LowerText').hide();
        $('#UpperText').hide();
        $('#AssetStatusChoice').change(function () {
            if($('#AssetStatusChoice').val()=="Fully Available")
            {
                $('#CommentsText').hide();
            }
            if ($('#AssetStatusChoice').val()=="Restricted")
            {
                $('#UpperLimit').show();
                $('#LowerLimit').show();
            }
            if ($('#AssetStatusChoice').val()=="Unavailable")
            {
                $('#Commentstext').show();
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your UpperTextbox and LowerTextBox ID in your browser using Firebug or other tool, to see if your textboxes don´t have any prefixes.